# GCP wont work after upgrading to OSX Mojave

Tags: google-cloud-sdk, macos-mojave

After I upgraded to OSX Mojave (Developer beta 2) I get an error every time I use GCP and also at reinstalling it.

```
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: No module named zlib
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import display
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import display_taps
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_printer_base
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_projector
    from apitools.base.py import encoding as protorpc_encoding
    from apitools.base.py.base_api import *
    from apitools.base.py import http_wrapper
    import httplib2
    from httplib2.python2.httplib2 import *
    import gzip
    import zlib
```

I have tried to reinstall python as well as zlib through brew; but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per page 3 of the release notes: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_beta_3/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_10_beta_3.pdf, you first need to install the package at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

`open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

Then you need to reinstall python2 from brew:

`brew reinstall python2`

After that you can `brew cask install google-cloud-sdk` and it will work

Comment: it's possible you need to reboot after installing the headers. I rebooted and did not test not rebooting