# gCloud SDK failed to install in macOS behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to install gcloud SDK while using a coporate network which works behind a proxy (and a VPN sometimes). I get proxy settings automatically using a pac.fcgi file (Automatic Proxy Configuration).

Now when I try to run ./install.sh in the terminal, I am constantly getting the following error

```
➜  google-cloud-sdk ./install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized usage data
and anonymized stacktraces when crashes are encountered; additional information
is available at <https://cloud.google.com/sdk/usage-statistics>. You may choose
to opt out of this collection now (by choosing 'N' at the below prompt), or at
any time in the future by running the following command:

    gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting true

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (Y/n)?  

ERROR: (gcloud.components.list) Failed to fetch component listing from server. Check your network settings and try again.
```

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44087310/1079901) which was having the same issue, but their problem was related to ipv6. I already have ipv6 disabled (I can't even enable it) and I am using ethernet to connect to the network. Thus the answer is not useful to me.

I searched for proxy related info about installation and found [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings). It asks for using a non-interactive installer instead and using gcloud command to set the proxy after installation. My problem is that I can't even install gcloud. I have tried with both interactive and non-interactive installers.

Any way I can install gcloud while being behind a corporate proxy.

PS: I am on macOS High Sierra and using zsh shell (already tried bash), in case it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the problem was I was unable to set proxy before installation of gcloud. The installation of gcloud basically set the CLI in the path and installs some required components (`core`, `bq`, `gsutil` etc).

So what I did is I added the following lines in my `.zshrc`

```
source <PATH to gcloud sdk>/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc
source <PATH to gcloud sdk>/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc
```

or if you're using bash, add these lines in your .bashrc or .bash_profile

```
source <PATH to gcloud sdk>/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
source <PATH to gcloud sdk>/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc
```

After that I restarted the terminal (or just run `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile` on terminal)

Now I was able to use gcloud commands. I ran `gcloud init`, set the proxy and then installed the required components using the following command -

```
gcloud components install core bq gsutil
```

And I installed `gcloud` without using the `install.sh` script.

PS: Run `scutil --proxy` to know the proxy settings set in your system.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 users who experience this issue. I installed the google SDK from the archived versions page. then used git bash to install using `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`. then added in environment variable manually to PATH to use commands.