# while installing Google cloud SDK getting below error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized usage data
and anonymized stacktraces when crashes are encountered; additional information
is available at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/usage-statistics. This data is
handled in accordance with our privacy policy
https://policies.google.com/privacy. You may choose to opt in this
collection now (by choosing 'Y' at the below prompt), or at any time in the
future by running the following command:

```
gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting false
```

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (y/N)?  y

This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
the Google Cloud Platform.

ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) Failed to fetch component listing from server. Check your network settings and try again.
Google Cloud SDK installer will now exit.
Press any key to continue . . .

Before i have installed it was working fine . but in between it's stopped working .

all path and python installed and path has been set .

Thanks and Regards, Tapas

Comment: Did you installed any firewall that may be blocking the traffic to the Google servers? It seems that the command is trying to run an update in your Cloud SDK and is unable to reach the servers.

Comment: Have you tried disabling IPv6 for the Cloud SDK installation as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087310/google-cloud-sdk-install-on-os-x-gcloud-components-list-failed-to-fetch-compo)?

Comment: Yeah sllopis , But don't know how again it's started working . Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a networking issue from the server you are trying to install Google Cloud SDK to Internet.
Can you make sure that you have Outbound access from the server?

If you are running behind a proxy, then you can try to set `export https_proxy=<your-proxy-url>` and then run `install.sh`